# What is the relationship between a list of symbols created by a specific name, and a expression with such a name?

Tags: evaluation, variable-definitions, symbols

I'm trying to create a list of symbols called "x" for calculating symbolic gradients of some functions, so I write:

```mathematica
x = Table[Symbol["x"][i], {i, 1, 3}]
```

why it complains `$RecursionLimit: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded`?

When I change the expression name from `x` to `a`, it works

```mathematica
a = Table[Symbol["x"][i], {i, 1, 3}]
```

Outputs

```
{x[1], x[2], x[3]}
```

I knew `c++` and `python`, but feel really hard to understand what happened when I type these symbol creation sentences in `mathematica`.

Is there any relevant document to read or learn about this topic? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! I would suggest reading this [Fast Introduction to Wolfram Language for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/). It also has special notes for people coming from Java/Python background. I think this will be useful for you to grasp some basic differences and peculiarities of Mathematica.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. The introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: Many thanks Domen and Syed. I didn't manage to find these precesie resource instead of the offical documents. I will now go to learn them and evaluate my problem again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The evaluator will evaluate an expression until nothing changes any more. Consider some code that gives a recursion:

```
x = Table[Symbol["x"][i], {i, 1, 2}]
```

To begin, the right side is evaluated and gives "x" the value:

```
{x[1],x[2]}
```

"x" has now the value {x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMqO6.png),x[2]}. This contains the symbol "x". Therefore this is again evaluated to:

{{x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMqO6.png),x[2]}[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMqO6.png),{x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMqO6.png),x[2]}[2]}

We can simulate this by giving different names to each new value of x:

```
x1 = Table[Symbol["x"][i], {i, 1, 2}]
x2 = Table[Symbol["x1"][i], {i, 1, 2}]
x3 = Table[Symbol["x2"][i], {i, 1, 2}]
```

[image]

On the other hand, the following does not create a recursion because after one step the evaluation stops because "x" has no value:

```
a = Table[Symbol["x"][i], {i, 1, 2}]
```